# having trouble converting csv to json using bash jq

Tags: json, bash, csv, jq, converters

I have one stream output stored in csv file, I need help converting csv to json:

my csv looks like:

```
cat output.csv
"k","a1",1,"b1","c1","d1",1
"l","a2",2,"b2","c2","d2",2
"m","a3",3,"b3","c3","d3",3
"n","a4",4,"b4","c4","d4",4
"o","a5",5,"b5","c5","d5",5
```

Required output:

note: I need key `configuration` to be added to json.

```
{
    "configuration": {
      "k": {
        "a": "a1",
        "number1": "1",
        "c": "b1",
        "d": "c1",
        "e": "d1",
        "number2": "1"
      },
      "l": {
        "a": "a2",
        "number1": "2",
        "c": "b2",
        "d": "c2",
        "e": "d2",
        "number2": "2"
      },
      .
      .
      .
    }
}
```

So far tried with jq:

my function is:

```
cat api.jq

[
  inputs |
     split(",") |
     map(ltrimstr("\"")) |
     map(rtrimstr("\"")) |
      {
        a: .[1],
        number1: .[2],
        c: .[3],
        d: .[4],
        e: .[5],
        number2: .[6]
      }
] | {configuration: .}
```

Output:

```
jq -nRf api.jq output.csv

{
  "cluster_configuration": [
    {
      "a": "a1",
      "number1": "1",
      "c": "b1",
      "d": "c1",
      "e": "d1",
      "number2": "1"
    },
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "number1": "2",
      "c": "b2",
      "d": "c2",
      "e": "d2",
      "number2": "2"
    },
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "number1": "3",
      "c": "b3",
      "d": "c3",
      "e": "d3",
      "number2": "3"
    },
    {
      "a": "a4",
      "number1": "4",
      "c": "b4",
      "d": "c4",
      "e": "d4",
      "number2": "4"
    },
    {
      "a": "a5",
      "number1": "5",
      "c": "b5",
      "d": "c5",
      "e": "d5",
      "number2": "5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: your input in your question will not work and does not create the output you have shown here. your api.jq has two times the key number.

Comment: There's no `cluster_configuration` string anywhere in your input or stated code, so the output doesn't correspond.

Comment: Anyhow -- the question at its core is how to make `a` a key under which you have your remaining data present as values, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insofar as your goal is to make `a` be a key, using `from_entries` is suitable for that:

```
[
    inputs |
    split(",") |
    map(ltrimstr("\"")) |
    map(rtrimstr("\"")) |
    {
        "key": .[1],
        "value": {
            number: .[2],
            c: .[3],
            d: .[4],
            e: .[5],
            number: .[6]
        }
    }
] |
from_entries |
{ configuration: . }
```

When run with

```bash
jq -R -f api.jq <output.csv
```

...the output is:

```json
{
  "configuration": {
    "a2": {
      "number": "2",
      "c": "b2",
      "d": "c2",
      "e": "d2"
    },
    "a3": {
      "number": "3",
      "c": "b3",
      "d": "c3",
      "e": "d3"
    },
    "a4": {
      "number": "4",
      "c": "b4",
      "d": "c4",
      "e": "d4"
    },
    "a5": {
      "number": "5",
      "c": "b5",
      "d": "c5",
      "e": "d5"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this anwser will not work if you have a comma inside any value of the output.csv . It only works in that special case, that you do not have commas inside the values. I have changed the first line to still valid csv: `"k","a,1",1,"b,1","c,1","d,1",1` . Check the output, it goes wrong.

Comment: @OliverGaida, yes, that's certainly true (I agreed that comma-splitting isn't valid for all possible CSV files in a comment on a different answer). But insofar as this was asked as a jq question first and foremost, I'm comfortable giving a jq answer and leaving the CSV-parsing aspects out-of-bound. peak has an answer that covers that part, and so does Stephen Quan, so there are ample alternatives available.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases) for several OSs), an interesting tool that supports multiple input/output formats:

```bash
mlr --icsv -N put -q '
    @map[$1] = {"a": $2, "number1": $3, "c": $4, "d": $5, "e": $6, "number2": $7};
    end { dump { "configuration": @map } }
' file.csv
```

```json
{
  "configuration": {
    "k": {
      "a": "a1",
      "number1": 1,
      "c": "b1",
      "d": "c1",
      "e": "d1",
      "number2": 1
    },
    "l": {
...
```

**note:** for forcing the numbers to be treated as strings you can use the `--infer-none` option.

Comment: i haved tried this and get : `mlr: cannot parse DSL expression.
Parse error on token "end" at line 1 column 79.`

Comment: @OliverGaida My bad, you need the semi-colon, fixed

Comment: I like your solution most. for me, miller is the swiss army knife for csv parsing.

Answer (score 1):

jq's `from_entries` can be used to generate objects with chosen keys.

In the below example, we first use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to convert CSV to JSON more robustly (in a manner that supports values with commas or quotes) before proceeding with `jq`

1. Add a header line at the top so Miller knows what key name to associate with each value:

   ```bash
   cat <(echo k,a,number1,c,d,e,number2) output.csv > output_with_header.csv
   ```
2. Convert the csv to json with miller:

   ```bash
   mlr --icsv --ojson cat output_with_header.csv > output.json
   ```
3. transform with jq, generating lists of maps with `key` and `value` elements and then combining them with `from_entries`:

   ```bash
   jq '{configuration: ([.[]|{key: .k,value: (.|del(.k))}]|from_entries)}' output.json
   ```

This results in:

```json
{
  "configuration": {
    "k": {
      "a": "a1",
      "number1": 1,
      "c": "b1",
      "d": "c1",
      "e": "d1",
      "number2": 1
    },
    "l": {
      "a": "a2",
      "number1": 2,
      "c": "b2",
      "d": "c2",
      "e": "d2",
      "number2": 2
    },
    "m": {
      "a": "a3",
      "number1": 3,
      "c": "b3",
      "d": "c3",
      "e": "d3",
      "number2": 3
    },
    "n": {
      "a": "a4",
      "number1": 4,
      "c": "b4",
      "d": "c4",
      "e": "d4",
      "number2": 4
    },
    "o": {
      "a": "a5",
      "number1": 5,
      "c": "b5",
      "d": "c5",
      "e": "d5",
      "number2": 5
    }
  }
}
```

All together as a oneliner:

```
cat <(echo k,a,number1,c,d,e,number2) output.csv | mlr --icsv --ojson cat | jq '{configuration: ([.[]|{key: .k,value: (.|del(.k))}]|from_entries)}'
```

Comment: jq is good for parsing json, not csv.

Comment: I'm expecting something like the below should work, but it isn't.
```[
  inputs |
     split(",") |
     map(ltrimstr("\"")) |
     map(rtrimstr("\"")) |
   {
   .[0]:
      {
        a: .[1],
        number1: .[2],
        c: .[3],
        d: .[4],
        e: .[5],
        number2: .[6]
      }
   }
] | {cluster_configuration: .}```

Comment: I wouldn't defend a thesis that jq is _good for_ CSV, but the OP's sample data doesn't hit any of the particularly tricky cases that require more dedicated tools to handle. If you're going to argue that jq is unsuited for handling the use case in question, I'd like to see that given support.

Comment: that is the point, the sample data doesn't hit any of the particularly tricky cases. But if the real data are more complex, you will need a robust csv-parser like miller.

Comment: My primary objection to this answer in its original form was that it spent more time/focus/attention on Miller (to address correctness concerns that might happen with _other_ input files, but weren't central to the OP's question) than on the jq changes that _were_ central to the question.

Comment: @OliverGaida instead of generating a CSV file you can add the header on the fly `{ echo 'k,a,number1,c,d,e,number2'; cat file.csv; } | mlr ... | jq ...`

Comment: @Fravadona yes thank you for the hint. It is like my oneliner at the end: `cat <(echo k,a,number1,c,d,e,number2) output.csv | mlr ... | jq ...`

Answer (score 1):

If robustness of CSV parsing is a concern, you could easily adapt
the parser at [rosettacode.org](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Convert_CSV_records_to_TSV).  The following converts the CSV rows to JSON arrays; since the "main" program below uses `inputs`, you'd use the -R and -n command-line options.

```
## The PEG * operator:
def star(E): (E | star(E)) // . ;

## Helper functions:

# Consume a regular expression rooted at the start of .remainder, or emit empty;
# on success, update .remainder and set .match but do NOT update .result
def consume($re):
  # on failure, match yields empty
  (.remainder | match("^" + $re)) as $match
  | .remainder |= .[$match.length :]
  | .match = $match.string;

def parse($re):
  consume($re)
  | .result = .result + [.match] ;

def ws: consume(" *");

### Parse a string into comma-separated values

def quoted_field_content:
  parse("((\"\")|([^\"]))*")
  | .result[-1] |= gsub("\"\""; "\"");

def unquoted_field: parse("[^,\"]*");

def quoted_field: consume("\"") | quoted_field_content | consume("\"");

def field: (ws | quoted_field | ws) // unquoted_field;

def record: field | star(consume(",") | field);

def csv2array:
  {remainder: .} | record | .result;

inputs | csv2array
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you raise this question as a `bash+jq` question, but, if it was a `bash+python` question, the solution would be trivial:

```py
# csv2json.py
import sys, csv, json
data = { "configuration": { } }
for [k,a,n1,c,d,e,n2] in csv.reader(sys.stdin.readlines()):
    data["configuration"][k] = { "a": a, "number1": n1, "c": c, "d": d, "e": e, "number2": n2 }
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Then, in bash (I'm assuming Ubuntu here), we could go:

```bash
python3 csv2json.py < output.csv
```